# Django how to build my query?

Tags: django

**EDIT - MORE EXPLAINATIONS**

This my view :

```
game = Games.objects.all()
plateform = Plateform.objects.all()

if request.POST:
    form = request.POST
    filters = {}
    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        if key in ['recruitment', 'on_plateform', 'on_game']:
            filters[key] = value

    team = Relation.objects.filter(**filters)
```

My template :

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <select name="recruitment" onchange=this.form.submit();>
        <option disabled {%if form.recruitment == Null%}selected{%endif%}>Recruitment</option>
        <option value="all" {%if form.recruitment == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>All</option>
        <option value="True" {%if form.recruitment == "True"%}selected{%endif%}>Open</option>
        <option value="False" {%if form.recruitment == "False"%}selected{%endif%}>Close</option>
    </select>

    <select name="on_plateform" onchange=this.form.submit();>
        <option disabled {%if form.on_plateform == Null%}selected{%endif%}>Plateform</option>

        <option value="all" {%if form.on_plateform == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>All</option>
        {%for plateform in plateform%}
        <option value="{{plateform.id}}" {%if form.on_plateform|add:"0" == plateform.id %}selected{%endif%}>{{plateform.name}}</option>
        {%endfor%}

    </select>

    <select name="on_game" onchange=this.form.submit();>
        <option disabled {%if form.on_game == Null%}selected{%endif%}>Game</option>
        <option value="all" {%if form.on_game == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>All</option>

        {%for game in game%}
            <option value="{{game.id}}" {%if form.on_game|add:"0" == game.id%}selected{%endif%}>{{game.title}}</option>
        {%endfor%}

    </select>

</form>
```

This is a filtering tool to get a list of any video games teams. I can filter by :

- recruitment statut (open or close)
- the game played (a list of video game in the data base)
- the plateform (a list of plateform in the data base like PS4, PC...)

So my query is dynamic to make the research more and more precise. That's why I'm using a dictionary called `filters`.

All my filters are working properly except, and that's is my problem, the filter where the value is `all`. 
I know It can not work like that but in your opinion, what kind of value may have I to put in my template to make it work ?

Many thanks for all your answers !

Comment: You want all objects of Relation ? Or all but just one field of it ?

Comment: Yes. All object where field is True AND False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you could approach this

1) Use `__in` lookup. `in` lookup accepts list

```
# for True option
Test = Relation.objects.filter(field__in=[True])
# for False option
Test = Relation.objects.filter(field__in=[False])
# for all option
Test = Relation.objects.filter(field__in=[True, False])
```

2) You could use kwargs unpacking

```
# for True option
qskwargs = {'field': True}
# for False option
qskwargs = {'field': False}
# for all option
qskwargs = {} 
Test = Relation.objects.filter(**qskwargs)
```

3) Just use if statement

```
if field not is None:
    Test = Relation.objects.filter(field=field)
else:
    Test = Relation.objects.all()
```

4) Use `Q` objects like @AaronVisang suggested in his answer

**Answering updated question**
You could pass empty value for all. Like this.

```
<option value="" {%if form.on_game == "all"%}selected{%endif%}>All</option>
```

And then in your code

```
if request.POST:
    form = request.POST
    filters = {}
    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        if key in ['recruitment', 'on_plateform', 'on_game'] and value: # here we check if value is not empty
            filters[key] = value

    team = Relation.objects.filter(**filters)
```

Comment: Thank you to sum up all solutions but I think I have to expose my entire problem because I don't think It will solve my issue.... Please take a look, I edit my question. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like that:

```
Test = Relation.objects.all()
```

You could use Q.

That would look like that.

```
from django.db.models import Q

Test = Relation.objects.filter(Q(field=True) | Q(field=False))
```

Comment: I know this synthax but I'm looking for another one for technical reason I won't explain here because It could be to hard to explain.

Comment: It would be `Q(field=True) | Q(field=False)`. You should use `| - OR` operator

Comment: Yes, and this is why it should be 'OR' otherwise your filter is wrong because it will be waiting for objects with `field` which are both `True` and `False`

Comment: I didn't know about Q and you're right, it's OR and not AND. I expose my entire problem. Please could you take a look because I don't know if your solution is good for my case. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a form like:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    recruitment = BooleanField(required=False)
    on_game = ChoiceField(required=False, ...)
    on_platform = ChoiceField(required=False, ...)

    def clean(self):
        result = super(FooForm, self).clean()
        for field_key in ['recruitment', 'on_game', 'on_platform']:
            if result[field_key] == 'all':
                result.pop(field_key)
        return result

form = FooForm(data)
form.is_valid()
Test = Relation.objects.filter(**form.cleaned_data)
```

Comment: I update my post to expose my issue more precisely. Thank you.